# iframeの内の要素を取得してその要素がクリックされたらcssを追加されるコードを書きたい

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

iframeの内の要素を取得してその要素がクリックされたiframeにz-index:1が追加されるコードを書きたいです。下記のコードでは何も変化がありませんでした。
教えてください。

```
<iframe id="Hello" src="https://example.jp/header.php"></iframe>

<script>

// iframe要素を取得
var iframeElem = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var iframeDocument = iframeElem[0].contentDocument || iframeElem[0].contentWindow.document;
// iframeで読み込まれているページ内のIDname要素を取得
var pElem = iframeDocument.getElementsById('sss')[0];
//iframeで読み込まれているページ内のIDname sssがクリックされたらiframe.style.zIndex= 1を追加する
$(document).on("click","sss",function(){
iframe.style.zIndex= 1;
});
</script>
```

Comment: ブラウザの開発者ツールのコンソールにエラーが出ていませんか。

Comment: @ int32_t
ブラウザーのConsoleには何もエラー出ていません。

Comment: では質問文のコードは実行されていない可能性が高いですね。getElementsById でエラーが出るはずなので。

Comment: @int32_t
有難うございます。
下記のエラーでています。

(index):152 Uncaught TypeError: iframeDocument.getElementsById is not a function
    at (index):152:27

Comment: var pElem = iframeDocument.getElementsById('sss')[0];を
var pElem = iframeDocument.getElementsById('sss');に変更しましたらエラーが無くなりましたが要望通りの機能はしてません

Comment: console.log(pElem)で見るとULLが戻ってきます。どこで間違えていますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click","sss",function(){
```

これは、「iframeの外のドキュメントで`<sss>`タグがクリックされたら実行する」という意味になります。`pElem` があるのですから、それを以下のように使う意図だったのではないでしょうか。

```js
pElem.addEventListener("click", function () {
```

また、iframe のロードを待つ必要もあるでしょう。「var iframeDocument = ...」以降のコードすべてを次のように関数でくるんでください。

```js
iframeElem[0].addEventListener('load', function() {
    var iframeDocument = iframeElem[0].contentDocument || iframeElem[0].contentWindow.document;
    // iframeで読み込まれているページ内のIDname要素を取得
    ...
});
```

Comment: 有難うございます。
はい、そのように実装してみましたが
Uncaught TypeError. pElem.addEventListener is not a functionのエラーが出ます。

Comment: ああ、ULL って null という意味でしたか?

Comment: 有難うございます。
はい、NULLです。